# ¿Cómo conocer el tipo de parámetro pasado a una función en Typescript?

Tags: javascript, angularjs-2.0, typescript

Tengo una duda con Angular 2 y typeScript

Tengo una interfaz asi:

```
export interface DataForm{
  cuenta:string;
  nombre:string;
}
```

Después tengo una función asi:

```
public  datas(x:DataForm){
  console.log(x);
}
```

Y tengo una variable `obj:number=20;`
Y se la paso como parámentro a la función que hice:

```
this.datas(this.obj);
```

En la consola me devuelve 20.

No se supone que al no ser del mismo tipo debería de mostrar error. 
Mi duda es cómo compruebo que el parámetro que recibo sea igual al tipo indicado de la función .

Esa función realmente recibiría los campos de un formulario con eso campos, pero me surgió esa duda, cómo muestro un error si no son del mismo tipo .
En el editor si me marca el error pero al compilar no muestra ningun error.
Creo que hacer un **type of** seria la solución, solo que quedo con la duda por qué no tira error al compilar.

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es que TypeScript se ha ideado como extensión de javascript, para que los compiladores puedan detectar este tipo de errores, por lo que solo te asiste en tiempo de compilación, esto es, "cuando estás en el editor", porque luego todo se **"transpila"** a JavaScript, y realmente te va a funcionar le pases lo que le pases (a priori). Por eso te muestra el 20 en consola. De hecho, el editor, es el que debería darte algún aviso, indicando el problema de tipos, en plan linter.

Para asegurarte, no estoy seguro de si bastaría solo con un `typeof`, ya que quizá te devuelva siempre un `Object` y no una clase concreta (al igual que pasa en JS). 
Lo más seguro en TS pasaría por usar un `instanceof`, tal que así:

```
   if (x instanceof DataForm) {
      console.log(x);
   } else {
      alert('error');
   }
```

Lo explican mejor en [la documentación oficial](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html)

La solución en vanilla JS es usar `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty`. Algo como lo que comentan por [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/135448/how-do-i-check-if-an-object-has-a-property-in-javascript)